# Webos LG TV cant see hebrew fonts

Tags: fonts, hebrew, webos, lg

webos application with a button and text in Hebrew,
i can see just symbols and not the text
Currently the application only includes a button and a link for test

the TV (LG) webos version is 4.9.7-15

tried adding "font-family:arial;" and "    font-family:Google Sans,Roboto,Helvetica,ariali,sans-serif;
"
but it did not help :-(

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>new app</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: #202020;
        }

        div {
            position: absolute;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            display: table;
        }

        h1 {
            display: table-cell;
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-align: center;
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }

 button{
       top:10%;
       left:5%;
       width:100px;
       height:50px;
       position: absolute;
       z-index: 2;
       text-align: center;
       vertical-align: middle;
       horizontal-align: center;
       line-height: 50px;
       background: green; 
       font-family:arial;
       }



    </style>
</head>

<script src="webOSTVjs-1.2.4/webOSTV.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="webOSTVjs-1.2.4/webOSTV-dev.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //sample code for calling LS2 API
    webOS.service.request("luna://com.palm.systemservice", {
        method: "clock/getTime",
        parameters: {},
        onSuccess: function (args) {
            console.log("UTC:", args.utc);
        },
        onFailure: function (args) {
            console.log("Failed to getTime");
        }
    });
</script>

<body>
    <div>
        <button onclick="window.location.href='http://192.168.0.17:8080/Garden_on';">
        גינה אור
        </button>   
        
    
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience, testing in the simulator and on my TV.

My code programmatically generates buttons with Hebrew titles, and they all showed Giberish.
[image]

However, when I any **changed the title of the page to Hebrew or added any Hebrew text directly into the HTML**, it worked.

[image]

Comment: hi
how do you 
"changed the title of the page to Hebrew" ?

Comment: In the HTML. I put the `title` tag in the head with a Hebrew name

Comment: I also tested it on my TV and it was working.

Comment: can you put am example it is not working on my TV :-(

Comment: As long as I have `<title>זה דף בעברית</title>` in my `html.index` it works for me.

Comment: I just noticed you're running on a very old WEBOS version. I'm testing my app on the 6, 22 and 23 simulators and on my rather new TV.

Comment: ok tnx it looks like it is not working on my WEBOS version :-(

Comment: Did you try on a simulator?

Comment: yes on the simulator its works (i can see the page in Hebrew)

Comment: Then I suspect it's your older OS.